# Cannot save foreign text to a SQL Server database table with a nvarchar field

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, internationalization

I have a requirement to have a multiline textbox that accepts any text from any language and stores this into the database for later use.

I am using Linq with ASP .NET 3.5 with a SQL Server 2005 database.

Any/all information you can provide me with is much appreciated :D

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: For example: 中国 in a textbox is just 2 boxes when it is on the way to the database (observed while debugging).  When the values are returned and displayed they come up as "??".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and fretting I found a some stuff I pieced together and used to come up with my ultimate solution.  This handles being able to insert any character I could throw at it:

I created 2 methods to handle the 2 scenarios I was looking to solve.

1st going from the user interface to the database.
I made sure that my web page was sporting the Unicode(utf-8) encoding content type.

```
public string unicodeToIso(string InStr)
    {
        if (InStr != null)
        {
            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(InStr);

            return iso.GetString(unicodeBytes);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Then I handled the return of the data to the user interface.

```
public string isoToUnicode(string InStr)
    {
        if (InStr != null)
        {
            // I originally used the string: "iso8859-1" instead of 1252
            // 1252 helped 'catch' ALL of the Chinese characters as opposed to most
            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); 
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(InStr);

            return unicode.GetString(isoBytes);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

I truly hope this helps anyone else out there that may be stumbling on this same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to Encode and Decode the text depending if you're updating/inserting or Viewing the data.

Look at System.Text.Encoding

Comment: I will have a look and see what I can find.  Thanks :)

Comment: Here is a scenario:
I have a DetailsView that selects/updates data, via an ObjectDataSource, from the database.
I edit the data and save a string that contains "中国".
When the data is then displayed in the ItemTemplate, it shows "??" where "中国" was in the string.
When I check the value that actually gets saved to the database field, it is "??".
While debugging, I can see that it is passing in square/rectangle characters in the place where "中国" should be.